# Debug/Release environments web.debug.config and web.release.config not present

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config, release

Basically what I need is the following. Depending of if I publish to production server or developpement server I want to use different databases. I've read a little on the topic and found out that I'm supposed to have a web.debug.config and a web.release.config And depending on which I choose from the dropdownlist in Visual Studio 2010 the appropriate web.config is being used.

The problem Is that I only have a Debug mode and a single web.config

If I add a release via the Configuration manager and call it Production I can only copy the configuration from Debug and cannot edit it.

I was usign this MSDN tutorial set it up: [Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kwybya3w.aspx)

and at step 3 i noticed I didn't have the option necessary to change the configuration

**Creating and Modifying Project Configurations
To create a project configuration**

1. Open the Configuration Manager dialog box.
2. Select a project in the Project column.

   **3. In the Configuration drop-down list for that project, choose New.**

I don't have the new option I can only use the debug option

[image: I don't have new configuration option]

My project Is actually a Website

[image: website]

In VB

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND IT:

Since I am using a webforms Web Site, this option is simply not available.